# Clarifying definition of block container and block box

Tags: html, css

I'm reading these MDN CSS Reference Concept articles and I find the terminology confusing or imprecise.

In the last [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Visual_formatting_model) it says:

1. A block container contains elements with `display: inline` participating in an inline formatting context (inline-level boxes), or only elements with `display: block` participating in a block formatting context (block-level boxes). This seems an impractical definition, especially when we've just learnt that an element that has `normal flow` has children with both `display: block` & `display: inline`. Are there two separate concepts here or have I just misunderstood?

---

2. If they are two separate concepts, this makes me question the definition of block box/block which, at first, is described as:

> a box generated by an element with display: block is called a "block box" or just a "block".

Then, at the end of the article it says:

> A block box is a block-level box that is also a block container.

In the first definition, technically, the element with `display: block` could appear anywhere. The second says it has to appear as a child to a parent that contains only blocks or inlines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML elements are not CSS boxes. Zero, one, or multiple boxes are generated for a single HTML element.

The primary concept you're missing is that of an anonymous box.

Suppose you have

```
<section>
  <span>Foo</span>
  <div>Bar</div>
  Baz
</section>
```

where `section` and `div` are `display:block` and `span` is `display:inline`, just as they are by default.

Now "Bar" and "Baz" get wrapped in anonymous inline boxes, and the span generates an inline box.

Further, because the block box generated by the `section` element would contain both inline boxes and block boxes, the `span` and "Baz" inline boxes are wrapped in anonymous block boxes. So the final box tree looks like this.

```
Block Box             <= from `section` element
  +--- Block Box      <= anonymous block box
  | +--- Inline Box   <= from `span` element
  +--- Block Box      <= from `div` element
  | +--- Inline Box   <= anonymous inline box from "Bar"
  +--- Block Box      <= anonymous block box
    +--- Inline Box   <= anonymous inline box from "Baz"
```

As you can see from this, no block box contains both a block box and an inline box as direct children, which is what your quoted paragraph is saying.

Comment: Wow I don't see how I would've discovered this from MDN (though happy to be proven wrong). Thank-you. If I'm correct, what I've learnt is `if a (`display: block`?) parent contains a mixture of *direct* block boxes & inline boxes, it wraps *direct* inline boxes in anonymous block boxes. Presumably if the parent contained only inline boxes, it'd leave them alone? P.s. Is that `foo` not considered wrapped in an anonymous inline block or because it's already the child of an inline element it's not tampered with?

Comment: I also read a block-level element is an element with: `display: block|list-item|table`. So basically this parent (`display: block;`) element won't tamper (wrap an anonymous block box around) any of these block-level elements as just described? If this is true, this helps me solve #2 by saying `a block container can only be `display: block`. A block = element with `display: block`. Therefore, a block-box is a block inside a block that has only 'block-level' children.

Comment: The first two sentences are correct. Also `display: flex|grid` are block-level. "A block container can only be display: block" is not correct. Elements that are `display: flow-root`, `display :inline-block` and `display: table-cell` generate block-container boxes, and the principal box of a list-item element is a block-container boxes. Note that a block-container box is a box that *potentially* contains block boxes, not necessarily one that does. It might contain just inline boxes. So the same is true of block boxes.

Comment: ...So `display:block`, or `display:flow-root` elements generate boxes that are both block-level and block containers, and these are therefore block boxes. In contrast,`display:flex` elements generate block-level boxes, but those boxes are not block containers. and `display:inline-block` elements generate boxes that are block containers but are not block-level. Neither of those would be termed block boxes.

Comment: Thanks @Alohci I think that pretty much clears it up. Why do inline-blocks generate boxes that are block containers but are not block-level? There seems to be 1 overlap of element with  `display: block` as it's a valid container and block-level element. Is it because inline blocks shouldn't contain blocks?

Comment: No, inline-blocks containing blocks is fine. Think of "block level" and "block container" as independent concepts. The "level"-ness of a box describes how a box interacts with its ancestor and sibling boxes, whereas "container"-ness describes how a box interacts with its descendant boxes. Does that help?

Comment: Not right now but it might become apparent later on. I was just trying to ask why inline-blocks generate boxes that are block containers but are not block-level

Comment: Because that's their raison d'être. To provide a method of putting a block container box into a line box alongside other inline level elements.

Comment: Thanks @Alochi. Do you think I good ask you one last parting question? Are block containers examples of containing blocks or are they different concepts completely?

Comment: They're related, but different concepts. A containing block isn't a box at all (yeah, I know). It's just a rectangle. A box has content, padding, border and margin areas, each of which has an outer edge that forms a rectangle. A containing block is, except for the initial containing block, is one of these rectangles. Sometimes it's the outer edge of the content area, sometimes the outer edge of the padding area.